# management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=* bug - Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

A [bug in Spring Boot Actuator exists](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30612) whereby if certain properties are used, `management.endpoint.health.probes.add-additional-paths=true` doesn't work in exposing the readiness endpoint at `/readyz` and the liveness endpoint at `/livez`. You get a whitelabel error page.

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are
> seeing this as a fallback.

Those properties include:

```
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.show-details=
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.show-details=
```

I need to use the management port by default so that I can use `/actuator/metrics` for monitoring. Therefore, in order to have reliable health checks, I need to expose the liveness and readiness endpoints on the main/application port, this is what the purpose of `management.endpoint.health.probes.add-additional-paths=true` is.

If I can't include additional checks in my readiness health check due to this bug, Spring Boot Actuator becomes unusable to me. Is there a workaround that can allow additional checks to be included while still allowing the readiness and liveness endpoints to be successfully exposed on the main/application port?

I have already tried using `management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.additional-path=server:/readyz`. This does not work.

I am using Spring Boot version 2.6.5.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour that you have described. With the configuration you've shown, accessing http://localhost:8080/livez and http://localhost:8080/readyz produces a 200 response indicating that the server is up. Please update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Andy Wilkinson, I have now reproduced what you described on Github. It works without management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=* and management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=*. However, it doesn't show details when management.endpoint.health.show-details=always is used.
I need to include a database check in the readiness group, is there a workaround that makes this possible, given the bug? Otherwise, Spring Boot Actuator is practically unusable for me.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect that I was able to reproduce/discover the *real* issue.

Comment: That's to be expected. `management.endpoint.health.show-details` configures details for `actuator/health`. It has no effect on individual health groups such as `actuator/health/readiness` or the health probes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the liveness and readiness health groups available at `:8080/livez` and `:8080/readyz` respectively with full details using the following configuration:

```
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.additional-path=server:/livez
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.additional-path=server:/readyz
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.show-details=always
```

```
$ curl localhost:8080/livez
{"status":"UP","components":{"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":1000240963584,"free":468848824320,"threshold":10485760,"exists":true}},"livenessState":{"status":"UP"},"ping":{"status":"UP"},"readinessState":{"status":"UP"}}}
```

This shows the same information as the liveness health group on the management port:

```
$ curl localhost:8088/actuator/health/liveness
{"status":"UP","components":{"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":1000240963584,"free":468845608960,"threshold":10485760,"exists":true}},"livenessState":{"status":"UP"},"ping":{"status":"UP"},"readinessState":{"status":"UP"}}}
```

The complete configuration used for this, based on your configuration in the question, was the following:

```
management.server.port=8088

management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.additional-path=server:/livez
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.additional-path=server:/readyz
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.show-details=always
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. Also, with this configuration I was able to add management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include= and management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include= and it still worked! Thanks a lot.